# Count number of visits between specific time frames

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table sample data is given below

```
Id  TokenNo TokenType   GeneratedAt
249 I1      W           2019-11-30 11:07:08.083
250 I2      W           2019-11-30 11:07:25.230
251 O1      W           2019-11-30 11:07:35.350
252 D1      W           2019-11-30 11:58:00.643
253 O2      W           2019-11-30 11:59:13.370
254 I3      W           2019-11-30 12:02:59.000
255 D2      W           2019-11-30 12:04:15.617
```

Script to generate sample data

```
insert into tab values 
(249,'I1','W','2019-11-30 11:07:08.083'),
(250,'I2','W','2019-11-30 11:07:25.230'),
(251,'O1','W','2019-11-30 11:07:35.350'),
(252,'D1','W','2019-11-30 11:58:00.643'),
(253,'O2','W','2019-11-30 11:59:13.370'),
(254,'I3','W','2019-11-30 12:02:59.000'),
(255,'D2','W','2019-11-30 12:04:15.617')
```

I wish to calculate the count of records (customer visits) in different time frames.

Expected Output

```
TimeFrame       Count
7 AM            0
10 AM           7    -- as per the sample data count between 10 AM and 1 PM
1 PM            0
4 PM            0
7 PM            0
10 PM           0
```

And after that i wish to convert the result to comma delimited output which i will do with the help of Stored Procedure

```
declare @res varchar(max)
select @res= coalesce(@res+',','')+  col from table
```

Comment: `7 AM` TimeFrame starts or ends value?

Comment: 7AM means count between 7 Am to 10 AM

Comment: so the interval time is 3 hrs? Can you provide script to generate the data?

Comment: yes interval time is 3hrs

Comment: insert into tab values 
(249,'I1','W','2019-11-30 11:07:08.083'),
(250,'I2','W','2019-11-30 11:07:25.230'),
(251,'O1','W','2019-11-30 11:07:35.350'),
(252,'D1','W','2019-11-30 11:58:00.643'),
(253,'O2','W','2019-11-30 11:59:13.370'),
(254,'I3','W','2019-11-30 12:02:59.000'),
(255,'D2','W','2019-11-30 12:04:15.617')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT 
substring(convert(varchar(20), GeneratedAt, 9), 13, 5) + ' ' + 
substring(convert(varchar(30), GeneratedAt, 9), 25, 2) AS GetTime
FROM #Temp

)
```

Here i'm Converting into the Time value as AM/PM

```
 SELECT * FROM
( 
SELECT '7 AM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'7 AM') AND Convert(datetime,'10 AM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT '10 AM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'10 AM') AND Convert(datetime,'1 PM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE 
UNION 
SELECT '1 PM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'1 PM') AND Convert(datetime,'4 PM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE 
UNION 
SELECT '4 PM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'4 PM') AND Convert(datetime,'7 PM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT '7 PM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'7 PM') AND Convert(datetime,'10 PM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT '10 PM' AS TimeFrame,SUM(CASE WHEN GetTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'10 PM') AND Convert(datetime,'1 AM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT FROM CTE
)a 
ORDER BY Convert(datetime,a.TimeFrame)
```

instead of hard code value use can use @Parameter or something else......as Per your preference

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: 7 AM 0,  
10 AM 1, 
10 AM 3, 
1 PM 0, 
4 PM 0,

Comment: As per your Sample Data...i have already Tested it out..it is right...i'm also adding my output to the answer you can checkout.....

Comment: as per the sample data between 10 AM and 1 PM there are 5 records

Comment: as per your sample data....11 to 12 ===5 records then 12 to 1 ==2 records.... it Convert into 11 to 12 as Come under 10AM timeframe and 12PM also come again same in 10AM timeframe ....10AM timeframe is  set between 10AM to 1 PM....there 7 records...you have alreadt Put expected out ....you  shown that count 7 in 10 AM thats Right..

Comment: Sorry. Yes , 10 am to 1 pm 7 records. But your query results only 1 record against 10 AM

Comment: @@SachuMine i put wrong query there...so check again....i edited my answer.....it will give you correct output...that's for sure...as per expected output..

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you can have the time frames in a CTE and then join with the table `tab`. You need to set the start date and end date.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = '2019-11-30 07:00:00.000'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2019-11-30 22:00:00.000'

;WITH FramesCTE AS
(
    SELECT @STARTDATE                 AS [start], 
           DATEADD(hh,3,@STARTDATE)   AS [end], 
           FORMAT(@STARTDATE,'hh tt') AS TimeFrame
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(hh,3,[start]), 
           DATEADD(hh,3,[end]), 
           FORMAT([end],'hh tt')
    FROM   FramesCTE 
    WHERE  [start] < @ENDDATE
)

SELECT TimeFrame, 
       COUNT(generatedAt) AS [Count]
FROM   FramesCTE
LEFT JOIN tab
     ON generatedAt >= [start] 
     AND generatedAt < [end]
GROUP BY TimeFrame
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44afe267a5611e63248fe37f0c28027e)

Then to generate the comma delimited string :

```
SELECT @res = COALESCE(@res + ', ', '') + TimeFrame + ': ' + cast([Count] as varchar(10))
```

Output :

`01 PM: 0, 04 PM: 0, 07 AM: 0, 07 PM: 0, 10 AM: 7, 10 PM: 0`

Answer (score 1):

I have used same data what you have provided , Now the query is mentioned below .
You can load this query either in table valued parameter or temp table and then you can use in your proc for coma delimited.

**Query is :-**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GeneratedAt, 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GeneratedAt, 9), 2) AS TimeFrame
    ,count(*) AS [count]
FROM dbo.sampledata
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), GeneratedAt, 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GeneratedAt, 9), 2)
```

Snapshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it would give incorrect time value as  14PM . I have tried like

SELECT left(FORMAT(GeneratedAt,'hh:mm tt'),2) +' ' +right(FORMAT(GeneratedAt,'hh:mm tt'),2)AS TimeFrame
    ,count(*) AS [count] 
FROM qms.TokenQHeader  

GROUP BY left(FORMAT(GeneratedAt,'hh:mm tt'),2) +' ' +right(FORMAT(GeneratedAt,'hh:mm tt'),2). This works fine, But my requirement is fixed time interval (3 hrs diff)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have declared @timeframe variable in your script.

```
DECLARE @timeframe INT = 3 * 3600; --equals to 3 hours in seconds
SELECT k.tf,
   COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT TokenNo, DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GeneratedAt) / (@timeframe) AS  tf
FROM tab
) k
GROUP BY k.tf;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what does this 19700101 means

Comment: It is UNIX birthdate and it is used as the reference. it does not really matter

Comment: I get tf column results as 145400    145403       145405 etc